# Php my admin mostrando código font

Tags: php, servidor, phpmyadmin

Instalei o mysql, php e apache de boas então reiniciei todos e fui instalar o php my admin até que surgiu um problema na hora de iniciar o mesmo no navegador ele mostra o código fonte, tentei fazer o que se pede neste tutorial [aqui](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Iniciantes-no-Linux/PHPMYADMIN-exbinindo-codigo-fonte) porém não adiantou, então alguém saberia como posso resolver tal problema ? ( Conteúdo em inglês não encontrei muito )

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se inicio com `localhost/phpMyAdmin` é apresentado erro 404, também criei um link simbolico como é dito neste artigo [aqui](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/MySQL/Problemas-na-instalacao-do-PHPMyAdmin).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você possui outro diretório com arquivo PHP e funciona? No NGINX você deve dizer para ele usar o `php-fpm`, no Apache, como é caso, salvo engano você deve usar o `php_admin_flag engine on` veja em http://askubuntu.com/a/407819